# ¿Como actualizar el listado de apps instaladas?

Tags: java, android

**Hola a todos**

**Les planteo mi problema:** requiero de la necesidad de poder actualizar o refrescar las apps instaladas del sistema, ya que mi aplicación le permite al usuario instalar apps pero de una manera root moviendo los archivos correspondiente (los archivos que muevo son el dex, las apk y la data, donde se incluye la lib y la cache) a la /data, pero el problema actual es como actualizar el listado de apps para que cree o muestre el icono de lanzamiento de la aplicación, ya se que cuando se reinicia el dispositivo todo esto se muestra, pero mi proyecto necesita la posibilidad de hacer estos pero sin tener que reiniciar el dispositivo.

Sobre mi código estos temas no los conozco y en mi investigación no encontrado información referente lo que quiero. Por esa razón no dispongo actualmente de un código.

Si tiene alguna idea estaré encantado de escucharlo.

**Código con que muevo los archivos**

```
        String[] command = {"su", "-c", "mv", "Ruta Al fichero", "Ruta a mover};

        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Si", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Este código la función que tiene es poder mover los archivos de un lugar a otro mediante comandos root, este código es el mismo que utilizo para mover los archivos a la /data.

Comment: Pon el código con el que lo haces.

Comment: El código que colocare sera el código que uso para mover los archivos a la data. Gracias